# THREE.js: Shadows cast by distant Light sources

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to create a scene with objects on a solar system scale.

Some examples of what I want are:

```
-When a small (on the order of 10m in diameter) object, crosses behind
a large object (earth sized), which blocks the light source
(THREE.DirectionalLight), the smaller object is shadowed by the larger 
object. 

-When a moon crosses between the light source and a planet, 
a shadow is cast on the planet.

-All objects must cast, and receive shadows (except stars, which only    cast).
```

I know that I should be shooting to "pancake" my shadow camera as much as possible, but with the variable nature of the scale that I need, this becomes very difficult to do.

What are some techniques or tricks that can be used when creating a shadowed scene on such a variable scale?

Is there some sort of logarithmic depth buffer for shadows (like there is for rendering)?

Or could I somehow leverage camera/trackball control events to dynamically adjust the frustum of the shadow camera? (as the camera(scene) gets further away, use a more coarse buffer/expand the shadow camera frustum)

Check out this JSfiddle for a relevant, but different example of my problem. These are two small objects, close together, with a very distant light source.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtcq070x/6/

Notice how the shadows flicker on and off, and there's shadowing on the front of the sphere (which there shouldn't be).

EDIT: I changed the jsfiddle to use a proper bias, and the ball now receives and casts shadows. notice how shadow darkness increasing worsens the self shadowing. Lowering shadow darkness isn't an option, because then the shadow cast to the plane disappears.

Also Here's exactly what I'm working on looks like (to scale solar system)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing in the jsfiddle is whats known as shadow acne. This can be fixed by using a non zero, small positive shadow bias value. Setting `light.shadowBias = 0.01;` seems to solve the problem in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtcq070x/4/. Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That helps for things that aren't receiving shadows, and also casting them. I realized the fiddle doesn't exactly match my scenario, because the sphere in front of the plane also must receive shadows. Here's the updated fiddle, which receives and also casts shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/mtcq070x/6/ and when it's receiving shadow I think it is self shadowing.

Comment: @Boogiechillin I dont quite understand whats wrong in the new fiddle. But the picture in the edit may be due to the shadowmap frustum is too big relative to your scene so you are only effectively using a few pixels in the shadowmap. You need to use smaller values of shadowleft, right etc, (as small as you can get to fit to scene really). And yes, this means you may have to dynamically calculate the shadow frustum that only captures the objects you are interested in.

Comment: The problem with the jsfiddle is effectively the same problem seen in my picture: there's shadowing on the front of the sphere. If you mess with shadow darkness in the hud, the front shadow disappears, but so does the shadow cast by the sphere, onto the plane. I pancaked the frustum as much as possible and still got what appears above. Also, switching the material of the sphere to be Phong (it was Lambert) seemed to smooth out the sharp edges of the front shadow.

Comment: I've found that modifying shadow bias to just the right value fixes this problem. However as my frustum changes, the value of the shadow bias also needs to change accordingly. This also depends on the size of the object, so this may not be a viable solution.

Comment: The fact that shadow darkness affects which pixel is in shadows is a very odd behavior to me. What I expected was that the shadow bias (along with shadow frustum parameters) determines which pixel is in shadow and then if the pixel is in shadow, shadow darkness affects how much light the shadow blocks. I dont know if shadow darkness affects which pixels is in shadow should be considered a feature or a bug.

Comment: Yes shadow bias need to be tweaked for different view is a known limitation of the shadow mapping technique that ThreeJS implements under the hood. There are various techniques to fix the various artifacts shadow mapping has, such as cascaded shadow maps.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct that shadow darkness does not affect which pixels are in shadow, that's definitely shown by a little time messing with shadow bias. It just appears that way because modifying (decreasing) shadow darkness hides the self shadowing that the object has, due to imprecise shadow bias.